# Is there a way to overcome the haphazard editing navigation in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, forms, editor

I am continually exasperated by navigating within the VBA editor. I'm continually forgetting the undocumented shortcuts like CTRL SHIFT F2, SHIFT F2, ALT F11, F7 etc, but I guess I just have to learn them. 
One ongoing frustration is looking for a subroutine ('Validate') (which is part of a User form 'Form 1') which I need to edit on numerous occasions.... 
So I have to right-click on "Form 1", View Code, then scroll all the way up to "(General)", click on this, go to the right hand drop down box in which I see 'Validate' amongst all the other form related routines, and click on it. Voila. But far too many steps. Should I be searching differently, or coding differently?

Thanks, Ali W

Comment: You can use Find to search across the whole vb project.  Ctrl+F >> Current project >> "Validate"

Comment: Get the MZTools VBE addin - it is better at searching etc

Comment: Thanks Tim, yes, another route, but after say debugging, you end up with the application (spreadsheet) in view, and then you have to press Developer, then View code before Ctrl-F is possible.

Comment: I'll try the MZ tools